# How to update a single value in a Set Data type in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

How to update a single value in a Set Data type in Cassandra. For example below is my set values in Cassandra. Let say the column name is column1 and value is

```
{'418_3', '521_4', '523_6'}
```

I want to update the value `'523_6'` to `'523_4'` so the updated value in Cassandra will be

```
{'418_3', '521_4', '523_4'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Update table set column1=column1-{'523_6'},cloumn1=column1+{'523_4'} where id='Your Id'`

The above query will remove the value from set and add another.